# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toggle') at toggleClass

Tags: javascript

I have a language selector (english or french) that is using toggleClass to switch language on click. However, I need to a script to run that will immediately change the default 'language' class to the 'language selected' class to make it appear that French is the default language on the page.

I used the following code to to swap classes on page load. I'm very confused because this was working as intended until this morning without an issue:

```js
function toggleClass(element, className1, className2) {
  element
    .classList
    .toggle(className1);
  element
    .classList
    .toggle(className2)
}

toggleClass(#languageSelector, 'language', 'language selected');
```

However today I received this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Private field '#languageSelector' must be declared in an enclosing class (at (index):190:12)
```

So I added '#languageSelector' to enclose the element, which ended up producing another error:

```
(index):184 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toggle')
at toggleClass ((index):184:22)
at (index):190:1
```

I'm seeing that other people have had a similar issue but I cannot figure out how to apply a solution to the existing code.

Altogether, this code:

```js
function toggleClass(element, className1, className2) {
  element
    .classList
    .toggle(className1);
  element
    .classList
    .toggle(className2)
}

toggleClass('#languageSelector', 'language', 'language selected');
```

is producing this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toggle')
at toggleClass ((index):184:22)
at (index):190:1
```

This functioned properly for several days. As far as I'm aware, nothing was added, removed, or changed about the existing website in any way but I don't see how that's possible. Why would this stop working over night?

I tried tracing the error and making adjustments, but I don't understand why reading .toggle is failing when it previously worked. Do I need to utilize a different way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Instead of trying to describe the code and why you think it should be correct, please provide a runnable [mcve] which includes actual code and demonstrates the problem.  As it stands, the error is telling you that `element.classList` is `undefined`, and I see no reason to expect otherwise.

Comment: My apologies, first time posting a question here and I just realized how jumbled and unreadable this post is. I'm attempting to clean it up now and I appreciate the link you passed me.

Comment: As (originally) tagged [tag:jquery] *but not* [tag:javascript] - and the use of `'language selected'` - perhaps you're trying to use javascript DOM methods as if they are jquery methods, eg `$(element).toggleClass(className2)` which *does* allow for multiple classes separated by space.   I've changed tags as no jquery seems to be in use.

Comment: Oof, yeah I'm quickly realizing this is out of my depth. I'm not a developer and my knowledge is extremely limited. This was a problem for another person's website that I was hoping I could assist with since they have even less knowledge than me. At this point I don't think I know enough to implement a solution. I apologize for wasting everyone's time and I'll just suggest that they either hire someone to solve this or leave English as the default language, which can be changed by a single click anyway.

Comment: Do you / they have jquery?   If so:  `$("#languageSelector").toggleClass('selected');` is all they need given what you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

> This functioned properly for several days.

No it didn't.  Some other code may have, but the code shown here did not.

> As far as I'm aware, nothing was added, removed, or changed about the existing website in any way

That sounds more like guessing than observing.  If you're not using source control then you don't know what code you used to have or how it's changed over time.  Now would be a good time to start using source control.

---

You're passing a string as the first argument to the function:

```
toggleClass('#languageSelector', 'language', 'language selected');
```

Then within the function you perform this operation on that string:

```
element.classList.toggle(className1);
```

A string has no property called `classList`.  Strings have never had such a property.

You *probably* meant to pass an element, for example:

```
function toggleClass(element, className1, className2) {
  element
    .classList
    .toggle(className1);
  element
    .classList
    .toggle(className2)
}

toggleClass(document.querySelector('#languageSelector'), 'language', 'language selected');
```

Of course, testing this produces another error indicating that you can't include a space character in a class name.  Which is suggesting that perhaps you meant something like this:

```
toggleClass(document.querySelector('#languageSelector'), 'language', 'selected');
```

For example:

```js
function toggleClass(element, className1, className2) {
  element
    .classList
    .toggle(className1);
  element
    .classList
    .toggle(className2)
}

toggleClass(document.querySelector('#languageSelector'), 'language', 'selected');
```

```css
.language {
  color: green;
}

.selected {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span id="languageSelector" class="language">test</span>
```